# How to represent a dynamic form with Play forms?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a form which is like a quiz/questionnaire type design to it.

So say the page is a quiz, it will display a dynamic number of questions on the page, and each question will have a list of checkbox options (the user can select 1+ checkboxes).

How can I represent this type of form in play?

```
case class Quiz(id: Int, name: String)
case case Question(id: Int, quizId: Int, title: String)
case class QuestionOption(id: Int, questionId: Int, name:String)
```

So you have a quiz, that has many questions.  And each question has multiple QuestionOptions.

So the form would be something like:

```
case class QuizForm(quiz: Quiz, questions: List[Question], options: List[QuestionOption])
```

For each question, you can select 1 or more QuestionOption.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the class the `Form` should bind to?

Comment: @m-z I updated the question, hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

I would nest the `Question`s within `Quiz`, and `QuestionOption`s within `Question`. That could make this a little more compact in the end.

```
case class Quiz(id: Int, name: String, questions: List[Question])
case class Question(id: Int, quizId: Int, title: String, options: List[QuestionOption])
case class QuestionOption(id: Int, questionId: Int, name: String)
```

A possible implementation of the `Form` would use `list`s of `mapping`:

```
val quizForm: Form[Quiz] = Form {
    mapping(
        "id" -> number,
        "name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "questions" -> list(mapping(
            "id" -> number,
            "quizId" -> number,
            "title" -> nonEmptyText,
            "options" -> list(mapping(
                "id" -> number,
                "questionId" -> number,
                "name" -> nonEmptyText
            )(QuestionOption.apply)(QuestionOption.unapply))
        )(Question.apply)(Question.unapply))
    )(Quiz.apply)(Quiz.unapply)
}
```

The very verbose part is the HTML form, which needs to contain all of these fields. Here is a sample of data a form would send (one question, multiple answers).

```
val data = Map(
    "id" -> "1",
    "name" -> "My Quiz",
    "questions[0].id" -> "1",
    "questions[0].quizId" -> "1",
    "questions[0].title" -> "What?",
    "questions[0].options[0].id" -> "1",
    "questions[0].options[0].questionId" -> "1",
    "questions[0].options[0].name" -> "red",
    "questions[0].options[1].id" -> "2",
    "questions[0].options[1].questionId" -> "1",
    "questions[0].options[1].name" -> "green",
    "questions[0].options[2].id" -> "4",
    "questions[0].options[2].questionId" -> "1",
    "questions[0].options[2].name" -> "blue"
)
```

The `name` fields of each of the question meta data / answers will need to have unique indices that bind them together. Here's a crude example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="My Quiz">

<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].quizId" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].title" value="What?">

<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[0].id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[0].questionId" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0].options[0].name" value="red">

<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[1].id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[1].questionId" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0].options[1].name" value="green">

<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[2].id" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[2].questionId" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0].options[2].name" value="blue">

<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[3].id" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="questions[0].options[3].questionId" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="questions[0].options[3].name" value="orange">
```

We can probably make this smaller by removing some of the title/name fields and ignoring them in the `Form`, since they shouldn't matter for persistence. But this gets rather verbose very quickly.

It's at this point I usually abandon `Form`s and go with pure javascript, as JSON is much simpler to handle (and read, in my opinion).

Comment: great thanks.  Would you use form input helpers do generate the "questions[0].options[1].questionId names?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the play form helpers. It might depend on how you're generating the HTML, but I imagine using `zipWithIndex` on `questions` and looping through that (with an inner loop on `options`) would do the trick.

Comment: I could also on a postback, loop through my questions and options, and look for the request.queryString and do it that way I guess.